# Why is Path.getFileName("/") inconsistent with "basename /"?

Tags: java, unix, nio

For all other paths, `sun.nio.fs.UnixPath` implementation (its [`getParent()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html#getParent()) and [`getFileName()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html#getFileName()) methods) seems largely compatible with `dirname` and `basename` utilities, standard for any UNIX system.

Still, for the root of a UNIX file system, both `Paths.get("/").getParent()` and `Paths.get("/").getFileName()` return `null`'s, which seems inconsistent:

```
$ basename /
/
$ dirname /
/
```

Moreover, `getFileName()` behaves differently from the older `java.io.File` implementation:

```java
Paths.get("/").toFile().getName();
```

returns an empty string.

Why?

Comment: Your problem is "why JDK designed in this way" or "how JDK designed in this way"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why?

Because the javadoc says so. Question already links to the javadoc, so you just have to read it:

- [`getParent()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html#getParent()) - *"Returns the parent path, or **`null` if this path does not have a parent**."*

  The root directory doesn't have a parent, obviously.
- [`getFileName()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html#getFileName()) - *"Returns a path representing the name of the file or directory, or **`null` if this path has zero elements**."*

  There are no "elements" in the path `/`, where "element" is defined as the text *between* separators.